# Can you have two sets of headsets plugged into xbox one controllers and still hear/talk in game?

Tags: xbox-one

I play online co-op multiplayer with my bro on the same console. I have 1 turtle beach ear force X12. We share it, but I am thinking about buying my own headset.

If we both plug in our headsets on our controllers, will we both have sound and be able to talk?

Comment: All I read was "problem with my brother"

Comment: I took out your second question, as it should be one question per post (and the second question is off-topic for us anyhow.)

Answer (score 3):

As long as both players' controllers are on, and synced with the Xbox, yes. You can have up to 4 players with headsets on the same console, all talking at the same time.